# python how to pass current instance to base class method

Tags: python, oop

i have :

```
class Observer(ABC):

    def append(self):
        self._subject.append(self)

    @abstractmethod
    def update(self):
        pass


class HexObserver(Observer):
    def __init__(self,subject):
        super().append(self)

    def update(self):
        print("HexObserver")
```

i need to pass the HexObserver instance to Observer _subject array
i keep getting :

```
TypeError: append() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Please also share how you are passing the HexObserver instance to Observer

Comment: I don't see `_subject`, `set_subject` and `get_subject` defined anywhere

Comment: The `append` method you've written only accepts one argument (`self`), which is passed implicitly when the method is called. But when you call `super().append(self)` you're passing `self` explicitly as well, which means you're passing two arguments to `append`, one implicit and one explicit.

Comment: Did you mean: `self.append()`?

Comment: i fixed the example for simplicity , still i have the problem when i try to pass the HexObserver  "this" ( in java for example ) to Observer append

Comment: @user63898 again, if you use `super().append()` it already does that implicitly, long-form it's equivalent to `super(HexObserver, self).append()`. You could *also* just do `Observer.append(self)`. But in this case, `self.append()` already calls the super-class `append`.